# PHP error in Apache2 and Linux Mint 18.3

Tags: php, apache2, linux-mint

I am using `Apache 2` and  `Linux mint 18.3`. My web root is `/var/www/html`. I placed there `info.php` which contains `<?php  phpinfo();  ?>`. I am getting output from that file. I placed a folder there named `api` and placed a file named `index.php`, I wrote below code inside that file.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
include 'database.php';

$start       = array('list', 'view');
$script_name = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

$vars = explode("/", trim(str_replace(str_replace('index.php', '', $script_name), "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "/"));

print_r($vars);
```

I am getting output like below

[image]

But I am expecting output like `Array ( [0] => en [1] => list [2] => sura )`

**UPDATE**

I added `.htaccess` file with below code in `api` folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But the result is same like before.

Comment: it means your file is not there or that you're doing url rewriting in the wrong way. If it's the latter please show your rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoklezCulloca. Where can I get `rewrite rules` ?

Comment: the link should be localhost/api/index.php

Comment: Have you tried googling the problem? If you have not yet setup a `.htaccess` file containing some rules, there is no way for this to work

Comment: Thanks @prasannaputtaswamy. I am getting same result in `localhost/api/index.php`.

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase. I added a `.htaccess` file.